# Vuforia даёт рейтинг правильной мишени (напольный кафель) в 0 звёзд

Tags: unity3d, vuforia, ar, augmented-reality

Мишень в реальной жизни - напольные плиты, а именно - узор из них.

Желаемый результат (наложение объекта на мишень не вызывает проблем) должен выглядеть примерно вот так (треугольников не будет на практике):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Для этого была нарисована мишень:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И, на всякий случай, ещё одна мишень:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но внутри Target Manager наблюдается следующая картина: 0 звёзд рейтинга у каждого изображения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Из-за такого малого рейтинга не работает Image Targeting, устройство не может определить мишень. В чём может быть проблема?